# How to create folder by Date time in batch file

Tags: datetime, batch-file, command-line, command

I am trying to create a folder by date time in my batch file using following code

```
@echo off & for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%A in ('date/t') do (
 set DateDay=%%A
 set DateMonth=%%B
 set Date=%%C
set DateYear=%%D
)
@echo off & for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%D in ('time/t') do (
set DateTime=%%D
)
set CurrentDate=%Date%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-0%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%
mkdir %CurrentDate%
```

using this I get  folder name as  `22-02-2021-010.01.37`
But if time  Hours is  in 1 to 9 hr my folder is displayed as
`22-02-2021-0 9.59.19` there is always a space in 0 and 9 and 1 to 9 hr is not displayed as 01,02,03 Hr

Answer Should Be:

```
22-02-2021-009.59.19
```

Comment: This could be useful to get the date time as needed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/9087250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and the correct method to get this is to use the date independently of the region `day/month` order, you can use `"WMIC os GET LocalDateTime"` as a source, since it's in ISO order:

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get FileName With Date and Time
Call :GetFileNameWithDateTime MyCurrentDate
echo %MyCurrentDate%
MkDir %MyCurrentDate%
pause & exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetFileNameWithDateTime <FileName>
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "%1=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%-%MyDate:~8,2%-%MyDate:~10,2%"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I also want seconds to be present in folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "CurrentDate=%Date%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-0%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%"
set "CurrentDate=%currentDate: =0%"
mkdir %CurrentDate%
```

substituting `0` for   in `currentdate`

Tips : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something which will work on any modern system, and still output the directory name in your specific format/order, regardless of user or locale settings, then…

you could do it like this from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=1-6 Delims=/: " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " 123"') Do @MD "%%I-%%H-%%G-0%%J.%%K.%%L"
```

or directly from the Windows [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line), `cmd.exe`:

```sh
For /F "Tokens=1-6 Delims=/: " %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Robocopy.exe \: . /NJH /L ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " 123"') Do @MD %I-%H-%G-0%J.%K.%L
```